# SharePoint 2013's Content Query Webpart filter by post category

Tags: sharepoint

I'm completely new to Sharepoint and I couldn't get this to work. How do you make a Content Query display blog posts under a specific category?
I have these parameters set up but it always says "This query returned 0 items."

I tried looking around and found this [possible solution](http://techblog-aj.blogspot.ca/2010/09/apply-filter-on-category-field-in.html) but I don't know if this still applies to 2013 and I don't exactly know where the webpart files are. For something simple as this I'm pretty sure SharePoint has something like this, I just don't know what to do/where to look.

I've been stuck on this for a couple of hours now. Any form of help is appreciated!

[current Webpart config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWVal.png)